# Phonegap fixed header and footer

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, cordova

We are developing `Phonegap` mobile app having fixed header and footer. But if any form elements focus the whole page become scrollable and header and footer losses its position fixed. In Android it is working fine but in iOS we face this problems.

---

**Update :-**

**Viewport Meta**

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, height=device-height, width=device-width ,target-densityDpi=device-dpi"/>
```

**Application Header**

```
<div data-role="header" id ="Top_content" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false" data-hide-during-focus=""> 
    <div id="jqm-homeheader" class="jqm-homeheader" align="center"> 
        <img src="images/logo.png" align="center"> 
    </div><!-- Logo closes-->
    <div data-theme="c" data-add-back-btn="true" > 
        <div id="search-box1">
            <form action="" onsubmit="custom_search();"> 
                <input type="search" name="search-product" id="search-product" value="" placeholder="Search" style="width:90%;" data-theme="s" />
            </form> 
        </div> <!-- Search Box--> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you add your code for header and footer here?

Comment: Do you have the keyboard plugin added? If so, you can set it so that the keyboard shrinks the webview (use KeyboardShrinksView=true in config.xml) so as to eliminate the scrolling behavior you are seeing.

Comment: @KerriShotts: yes i have added the keyboard plugin and KeyboardShrinksView=true in config.xml but it does not work for me :(

Comment: <div data-role="header" id ="Top_content"  data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false" data-hide-during-focus="">
<div id="jqm-homeheader" class="jqm-homeheader" align="center">
    <img src="images/logo.png" align="center">
</div><!-- Logo closes-->
<div data-theme="c" data-add-back-btn="true" >
<div id="search-box1">
<form action="" onsubmit="custom_search();">
<input type="search"  name="search-product" id="search-product" value="" placeholder="Search" style="width:90%;" data-theme="s" /></form>
</div> <!-- Search Box-->
</div>
</div>

Comment: What's in your meta viewport tag? It's possible that's getting in the way.

Answer (score 2):

It is a bug. I had the same and its quite annoying. Add this lines in tag head:

```
<script>     
$(document).on("mobileinit", function () {
  $.mobile.fixedtoolbar.prototype.options.tapToggle = false;
  $.mobile.fixedtoolbar.prototype.options.hideDuringFocus ="";
});
</script>
```

Add them after:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="phonegap.js"></script>
```

If you have jquery and jquery mobile, it must be like:

****CHANGE SRC****

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="phonegap.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/libs/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" ></script>
<script>     
$(document).on("mobileinit", function () {
  $.mobile.fixedtoolbar.prototype.options.tapToggle = false;
  $.mobile.fixedtoolbar.prototype.options.hideDuringFocus ="";
});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/libs/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.js" ></script>  
 <!-- css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="js/libs/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" />
```

Comment: the above code does not work for me. :(. plzz suggest.

Comment: <div data-role="header" id ="Top_content"  data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false" data-hide-during-focus="">
<div id="jqm-homeheader" class="jqm-homeheader" align="center">
    <img src="images/logo.png" align="center">
</div><!-- Logo closes-->
<div data-theme="c" data-add-back-btn="true" >
<div id="search-box1">
<form action="" onsubmit="custom_search();">
<input type="search"  name="search-product" id="search-product" value="" placeholder="Search" style="width:90%;" data-theme="s" /></form>
</div> <!-- Search Box-->
</div>
</div>